# Show link based on role

Tags: users

In page.tpl.php I'm displaying a link for user page. For an example:

```
<?php echo l(t("My offers"), 'user/' . $user->uid . '/offers'); ?>
```

So when a user clicks on the link it goes to user/uid/offers.

Now I want to show this link only based on a role. 
Let's say we have a role "Seller" that has unique ID 5 in the database. 
How can I set

```
<?php echo l(t("My offers"), 'user/' . $user->uid . '/offers'); ?>
```

to be visible only when a user has a role "Seller"?-

Comment: Related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/70465/16495

Comment: It shows how to access $user in tpl. If you `var_dump($user)`, you will see `$user->roles`. Come on, you can test variables on your own :D

Comment: I've tested the code, but it didn't help. It only shows the array with details of the user. I didn't find how can I set link that will be visible only for a specific role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got answer from drupal.org and this is the right solution:

```
<?php
if(isset($user->roles[5]))
{
  echo l(t("My offers"), 'user/' . $user->uid . '/offers');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a non-coding method, you can create a block or for more control over the content a Views block that shows for certain roles.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in following way say your seller roll machine_name is **profile_seller** then,

<

```
?php
if($user->**profile_seller** == "yes")
{
  echo l(t("My offers"), 'user/' . $user->uid . '/offers');
}
?>
```

Let us know if it works